# How to divide logic of returned object's creating between base and derived class in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, design-patterns, reflection

How to divide logic of object's creating between base and derived class without redundant methods, copying objects, passing by reference and other dirty hacks?
This is example. I need write more details. I need write more details. More details.

```
public abstract class Base
{
    protected int Property1;
    protected int Property2;

    public View GetView()
    {
        View view = new View();
        view.Property1 = Property1.ToString();
        view.Property2 = Property2.ToString();
        return view;
    }
}

public class Derived1 : Base
{
    int Property3;

    public override View GetView()
    {
        View1 view = new View1();
        view.Property3 = Property3.ToString();
        //return view;
        //return base.GetView();
        //return view UNION base.GetView(); ???
    }
}

public class Derived2 : Base
{
    int Property4;

    public override View GetView()
    {
        View2 view = new View2();
        view.Property4 = Property4.ToString();
        //return ???
    }
}

public abstract class View
{
    public string Property1;
    public string Property2;
}

public class View1 : View
{
    public string Property3;
}

public class View2 : View
{
    public string Property4;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are `View1` and `View2` connected? Implementing the same interface for example?

Comment: "I need write more details. I need write more details. More details." Less caffeine. I've no clue what you're trying to accomplish because your example is so vague.

Comment: @nvoigt They're derived from View. They can easy implement interface IView if needed.

Comment: @DanWilson Sorry, I thought my example is clear enough. The question in comments, what should I return from derived class?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibility. The View is passed to a base setup method to setup the base specific fields.

```
public abstract class Base
{
    protected int Property1;
    protected int Property2;

    protected void Setup(View view)
    {
        view.Property1 = Property1.ToString();
        view.Property2 = Property2.ToString();
    }
}

public class Derived1 : Base
{
    int Property3;

    public View GetView()
    {
        View1 view = new View1();
        view.Property3 = Property3.ToString();
        Setup(view);
        return view;
    }
}

public class Derived2 : Base
{
    int Property4;

    public View GetView()
    {
        View2 view = new View2();
        view.Property4 = Property4.ToString();
        Setup(view);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose generics could help to do exactly what you wish - strongly typed results and ability to reuse logic from base class. Or probably I missed your point

```
public abstract class Base<T>
    where T : View
{
    protected int Property1;
    protected int Property2;

    public abstract T GetView();
}

public class Derived1 : Base<View1>
{
    int Property3;

    public override View1 GetView()
    {
        View1 view = new View1();
        view.Property3 = Property3.ToString();
        return view;
    }
}
```